# Can't refresh idToken after expiration for a google sign in

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I use flutter google_sign_in package to implement google login in my app and it dose work but after 1h the idToken expires and I can't refresh it even if I call signInSilently() can anyone help ?

Thanks!

```
Future<bool> signInGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(ViewState.Busy);
    try {
      var u = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      if (u==null) u = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      // Authenticate the GoogleUser
      // This will give back an access token and id token
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await u.authentication;
      await _api.loginExternalG(googleAuth.idToken);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
    setState(ViewState.Idle);
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the test virual device had a wrong date & time set ..